# ImportError: No module named connector

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-2.7, mysql-connector

Getting error as in the title

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F27)
python 2.7

path to mysql /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

echo $PYTHONPATH
:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/


pip list
mysql-connector-python (2.0.4)
mysql-connector-python-cext (2.1.3)


import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', database='database')
cnx.close()

File "/Volumes/docs/python/TwtWth/mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named connector

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector')
print "\n".join(sys.path)
import mysql.connector

ImportError: No module named connector
```

Does any body know any further steps to dig?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking to make sure that your pip packages are included in `$PYTHONPATH`?

Might be something to check

Comment: in the post above echo $PYTHONPATH
:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: What happens when you ``ls -lah /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/``. is that where ``pip`` is installing to? You can also try ``import site; site.getsitepackages()``

Comment: @StephenG <code>
    drwxr-xrwx  20 root      wheel   680B Oct 24 23:48 . <br/>
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root      wheel   102B Sep 10  2014 .. <br/>
    -rw-r--r--@  1 UserName  wheel    18K Oct 25 18:59 .DS_Store <br/>
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 7161      owner    52K Sep 10 13:32 _mysql_connector.so <br/>
    drwxr-xrwx   6 root      wheel   204B Oct 24 23:41 mysql <br/>
    drwxr-xrwx   7 root      wheel   238B Oct 24 19:04 mysql_connector_python-2.0.4-py2.7.egg-info <br/>
    -rw-r--r--   1 7161      owner   1.5K Sep 10 13:32 mysql_connector_python_cext-2.1.3-py2.7.egg-info </code>

Comment: Have you tried running python as root with ``sudo`` and still seeing if you get the same errors? It could be a permissions problem ...